# The Special Table

Tags: puzzle

Consider a $n\times n$ table which is filled with numbers $1,2,3,...,n^2$ (in no particular order).We'd call such table "Special" if the sum of each column and each row and each diameter is a constant number.For what $n$s do we have a Special Table?

Comment: There are normal magic squares of all orders except $n=2$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx I can't get what you mean by that can you make an example?

Comment: @FuriousMathematician: What mjqxxx is saying that the thing you call a "special table" is commonly known as a (normal) [magic square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square), and it is well known that they exist for all $n\ge 3$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I see... now how would you prove that?

Answer (score 0):

What you call a "special table" is commonly known as a (normal) "magic square".

The [Wikipedia article on magic squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square) links to various methods for constructing them explicitly for all side lenghts except $2$. (One easily sees that the $n=2$ case is impossible).